# Evaluate random function for each row

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the following sql:

```sql
SELECT SERIES.TIME AS TIME
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(
             CAST('now' AS TIMESTAMP) - cast('1 month' AS INTERVAL),
             CAST('now' AS TIMESTAMP),
             CAST('1 day' AS INTERVAL)
         ) AS SERIES (TIME)
         CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT * FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, (floor(random() * 10)::int))) as RANDOM_TABLE
```

This should generate a series of dates with an interval of one hour in it. What I now try to get is each day to be randomly fanned out. I have noticed that in the above sql statement `random()` is only evaluated once even though it is in a subquery.

Now without the `CROSS JOIN` I get:

```
| 2019-02-13 |
| 2019-02-14 |
| 2019-02-15 |
```

and with the `CROSS JOIN` I now get for example:

```
| 2019-02-13 |
| 2019-02-13 |
| 2019-02-13 |
| 2019-02-14 |
| 2019-02-14 |
| 2019-02-14 |
| 2019-02-15 |
| 2019-02-15 |
| 2019-02-15 |
```

What I would like to have is a random number each time I fan out. E.g.:

```
| 2019-02-13 |
| 2019-02-14 |
| 2019-02-14 |
| 2019-02-14 |
| 2019-02-14 |
| 2019-02-15 |
| 2019-02-15 |
| 2019-02-15 |
```

How do I need to modify my query to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is premature optimization.  Postgres "forgets" that `random()` is volatile and should be called each time.

Here is a fix:

```
SELECT SERIES.TIME AS TIME
FROM (SELECT s.time, (floor(random() * 10)::int) as num
      FROM GENERATE_SERIES(now() - interval '1 month' , now(), interval '1 day') s(time)
         ) AS SERIES (TIME)
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL
         GENERATE_SERIES(1, num) as RANDOM_TABLE
```

And a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ae4c914dc45744e1cbd8e631fdf35aa1).

Note that I made some substitutions that seem more "Postgres-like" -- using `now()`, `interval` and so on for date arithmetic rather than converting strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT t.time
FROM (
  SELECT series.time as time, (floor(random() * 10)::int) as num_days
  FROM generate_series(now() - interval '1 month', now(), interval '1 day') AS series (time)
) t
  CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, num_days)
```

Comment: . . Do you know what `cross join` works here?  To me, it seems like `cross join lateral` is required.  Is this a Postgres extension?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: `lateral` is only required for sub-queries/derived tables. If you use a set returning function, lateral is implied